# Cannot import django_countries yet is installed

Tags: django

```
(operation-fix) bash-3.2$ ls
Pipfile     Pipfile.lock    README.md   src
(operation-fix) bash-3.2$ pip freeze
Django==2.0.7
django-countries==6.1.2
pytz==2020.1
(operation-fix) bash-3.2$
```

above shows django_countries in the root of project. Should it not be in the root?

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
```

above has error unable to import. Yet have added to INSTALLED APPS in settings.py in src.

Don't understand what I am missing (am new to python) yet this seems very obvious if you know what to look for. Thanks!

---

SOLUTION:

Somehow I ended up with a venv without a bin folder. I ran source bin/activate but it did not work. So I just started again created a new venv and it worked.

I was accessing the pip environment using `pipenv shell` to get around the issue and also my local server was running fine - which is weird. But regardless - just start again with a fresh venv to sort the problem.

Comment: How are you running Django? Are you sure it's using the same virtual env `operation-fix`? You could also try running `python -m pip freeze` (which will definitely use the same virtual env as `python`) to double check that `django-countries` is installed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ran python -m pip freeze in root of project and returned same imports as above. Though I didnt think of this potential problem will look into it thanks. Any other advice is welcome!

Comment: @Alasdair i believe you may be correct that it is a venv issue.

Comment: If the package is installed in the env, but Django gives an import error, that suggests you are running Django in the wrong env. I can't give any other advice without knowing how you are running Django or seeing the full traceback.

Comment: it is sorted now - thank you for your help sir